# How to take output of 1 IntelliJ project and import to another?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I have a library that I am developing in a seperate project in IntelliJ that I need to reference in another project.

How should I go about this in IntelliJ?

Would it be possible to do it like this:

Say I am writing a library to perform wiki markup in a seperate IntelliJ project, and I have a spring web project also in another IntelliJ project.

If I want to work on the library project, I can do it in a seperate IntelliJ project, but at the same time if I want to have that library available for editing in my spring project I can do it there also in the same project.

Is this possible or is it just complicating things?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use a multi-module project.  If you're used to Eclipse, your "project" is like an Eclipse "workspace", and a "module" is like an Eclipse "project".  You can tell one module that it's dependent on another.